# MVC IPagedList with model type error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get the error in my MVC 5 App:

CS1061: 'IPagedList' does not contain a definition for 'TargetContact' and no extension method 'TargetContact' accepting a first argument of type 'IPagedList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I saw the answers here but I still don’t get it done :(
It's probably pretty easy to solve.

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTargetContact = null, int page = 1)
        {
                var model =
                from r in db.Outreach
                orderby r.TargetContact descending
                where (r.TargetContact.StartsWith(searchTargetContact) || searchTargetContact == null)
                select new Models.OutreachSetListViewModel
                {
                    TargetContact = r.TargetContact,
                    NextOutreachStep = r.NextOutreachStep,
                    GoalOfOutreach = r.GoalOfOutreach,
                                    };
            model.ToPagedList(page, 10);

 return View(model);

namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    public class OutreachSetListViewModel
    {
        public string NextOutreachStep { get; set; }
        public string TargetContact { get; set; }
        public string GoalOfOutreach { get; set; }
   }
}

@model IPagedList<OutreachSetListViewModel>
<table class="table" id="networkingList">
    <tr>

        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TargetContact)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NextOutreachStep)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GoalOfOutreach)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TargetContact)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NextOutreachStep)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GoalOfOutreach)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model in the view is `IPagedList<OutreachSetListViewModel>`, so when you are looping though the model, each item does have a `TargetContact`.

However, when you are displaying the header, the model for the `DisplayNameFor` is not the individual item, but the list. The list does not have the `TargetContact` property so we have to get it from one of the items in the list.

In this case, we check to see if there are any elements in the list, and if there are, get the `TargetContact` from the first element.

```
@if(Model.Any())
{
    <tr>

        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TargetContact)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].NextOutreachStep)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].GoalOfOutreach)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
}
```

**Controller**

You are not doing anything with the returned value from `model.ToPagedList(page, 10);`

Save it to a value and pass it in to the view:

```
var vm = model.ToPagedList(page, 10);
return View(vm);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it recognizes the properties but I get the following error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[WebApplication11.Models.OutreachSetListViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[WebApplication11.Models.OutreachSetListViewModel]'.`

Comment: Updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am a late, but then again I was phasing this problem today and solved by using the same methodology used when it's an IEnumerable all I did was replace IEnumerable with IPagedList and it worked like a charm.

```
public static string DisplayNameFor<TModelItem, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModelItem>> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModelItem, TResult>> expression)
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlHelper));
        if (expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        return htmlHelper.DisplayNameForInnerType(expression);
    }

public static string DisplayNameFor<TModelItem, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<IPagedList<TModelItem>> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModelItem, TResult>> expression)
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlHelper));
        if (expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        return htmlHelper.DisplayNameForInnerType(expression);
    }
```