# Why am I getting an error when linking my projects model to IPagedList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

When following the tutorial on Microsoft's website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), I get to the "Add paging links to the Student index view" section and run into an issue.  I have installed PagedList.Mvc and the dependency PagedList.  On my Index view, I run into the following error:
**error CS1061: 'PagedList.IPagedList' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'PagedList.IPagedList' could be found** The versions of both packages are:

PagedList - 1.17.0.0

PagedList.Mvc - 4.5.0.0

These are the references called at the top of my view:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<InventoryTracking.Models.Item>
```

Here is the relevant code in my controller:

```
var items = from s in db.Items select s;
...
int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
return View(items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are passing PagedList from controller to view

eg:

```
List<Item> ItemList = db.Items.ToList();
return view(ItemList.ToPagedList(page, PageCount));
```

where your page is current page number and page count is total items on one page

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error message even after passing the ItemList to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by looking at this link [MVC IPagedList with model type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361385/mvc-ipagedlist-with-model-type-error). The issue was in my view, I was using @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model) which worked when the model was based off of the item before I changed to an IPagedList.  It didn't help that I have a class named 'Model' which made things even more confusing when looking for an answer.

```
//Incorrect 
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Assigned_User)

//Correct
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Assigned_User)
```